# i want to remove the name which is used in last random generate from my names so it is always unique & not repeating in next generate

Tags: python, random

```
import random

names = ["raja","laxman","jay","ajay","lopo", "tost","lola","manish", "Vishal"]

idx = random.randint(0, len(names)-1)
    My_lable.config(text = (f"Thief: {names[idx]}") )
```

#for example if I get raja in 1 generate it should be eliminated from next #generate once all names are used only then it should start using all names again.

Comment: If you just want to prevent the last result to be used, just store the old result, redo the line if you got the same result. If you want the generated sequence to exhaust all members, shuffle the list instead

Comment: hi, @Martheen can share an example of how to do it. I am new to python.

Comment: Which one do you need? Just comparing the last one, or shuffle? If it's comparing the last one, try it first, I believe the description is clear enough to do yourself, if it's shuffling, there's a built-in feature https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution using a function with side-effects. I'd prefer using a pure function, but this should serve your purpose and is probably more trivial.

```
import random

names = ["raja","laxman","jay","ajay","lopo", "tost","lola","manish", "Vishal"]
excluding = []

def get_rand():
    name = names[random.randint(0, len(names)-1)]
    if len(excluding) == len(names):
        print("No more names to pick from")
        exit()
    if name in excluding:
        return get_rand()
    excluding.append(name)
    return name
    
for i in range(10):
    print(get_rand())
```

An another approach would be to mutate the list of names where you remove the name that has already been selected from the list, but this is only possible if your list is not used elsewhere.

import random

```
names = ["raja","laxman","jay","ajay","lopo", "tost","lola","manish", "Vishal"]

def get_rand():
    if not len(names):
        print("No more names to pick from")
        exit()
    idx = random.randint(0, len(names)-1)
    name = names[idx]
    del names[idx]
    return name
    
for i in range(10):
    print(get_rand())
```

Comment: Deleting will probably not meet OP's requirement. OP wants to be able to re-sample all the original names in the list after exhausting them once. Don't blame you though - that part seems to have been added in a subsequent edit of the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preserve the original list of names, you can make a duplicate list and work on that. Otherwise, just modify your code to use `pop()` instead:

```
import random
names = ["raja", "laxman", "jay", "ajay", "lopo", "tost", "lola", "manish", "Vishal"]
idx = random.randint(0, len(names) - 1)
My_lable.config(text = (f"Thief: {names.pop(idx)}"))
```

`pop()` returns the entry from given index and removes it from the list.